# Push notification not received in my device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing hybrid mobile app using ionic framework and MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1. The application supports push notification and we are trying to send the notifications from the command line.

After all the set up has been done, when trying to send push notification we are getting a success response - but the notification has not been received in android device. I have also subscribed the device for push notification and tagged it.

Code to tag my application:

```
function isPushSupported() {
    var isSupported = false;
    if (WL.Client.Push){
        isSupported = WL.Client.Push.isPushSupported();
    }
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", JSON.stringify(isSupported), [
     {
        text : 'Close',
        handler : function() {

        }
     },{
        text : 'OK',
        handler : function(){
        if (WL.Client.Push) {
            WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
                WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Ready to subscribe", [
                    {
                        text : 'Close',
                        handler : function() {}
                 },{
                      text : 'ok',
                      handler : function() {
                      subscribeToSampleTag1();
                      subscribeToSampleTag2();
                      isSubscribedToTags();
                 }
                 }
                 ]);
                    $('.subscribeToTagButton').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.unsubscribeFromTagButton').removeAttr('disabled');
                };
      }
        }
       }
      ]);
}
    function subscribeToSampleTag1() {
      WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag("tag1", {
      onSuccess: subscribeTagSuccess,
      onFailure: subscribeTagFailure
    });
    }
    function subscribeToSampleTag2() {
      WL.Client.Push.subscribeTag("tag2", {
      onSuccess: subscribeTagSuccess,
      onFailure: subscribeTagFailure
      });
     }
    function isSubscribedToTags() {
      var subscribedTagsSample1 = WL.Client.Push.isTagSubscribed("tag1");
      var subscribedTagsSample2 = WL.Client.Push.isTagSubscribed("tag2");
      WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", 'sample-tag1: ' +          subscribedTagsSample1 + '\n' + 'sample-tag2: ' + subscribedTagsSample2, [ {
      text : 'Close',
      handler : function() {}
        }
       ]);
       }
     WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Provider notification data: " + JSON.stringify(props), [ {
           text : 'Close',
            handler : function() {
        WL.SimpleDialog.show("Tag Notifications", "Application notification data: " + JSON.stringify(payload), [ {
            text : 'Close',
            handler : function() {}
          }]);
    }
}]);
```

};

Changes in adapter.xml:

```
<procedure name="sendBroadcastNotification" />
<procedure name="sendTagNotification" />`
```

Changes in adapter-impl.js:

```
function sendBroadcastNotification(applicationId, notificationText) {
    var notificationOptions = {};

    notificationOptions = getNotificationOptions(notificationText);

    WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions);

    return {
        result : "Notification sent to all users."
    };
}

function sendTagNotification(applicationId,notificationText, notificationTags) {
    var notificationOptions = {};

    notificationOptions = getNotificationOptions(notificationText, notificationTags);

WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId, notificationOptions);

return {
    result : "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): '" + notificationTags + "'."
  };
  }

  function getNotificationOptions(notificationText, notificationTags){

var notificationOptions = {};

notificationOptions.message = {};
notificationOptions.target = {};
notificationOptions.settings={};

if(notificationTags != undefined && notificationTags != null){
    var tags = notificationTags.split(",");
    notificationOptions.target.tagNames = tags;
}

notificationOptions.message.alert = notificationText;

// set raw notification properties for MPNS
notificationOptions.settings.mpns = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.raw = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.raw.payload = {"custom":"data"};

// set toast notification properties for MPNS
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text1 = "Toast title";
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.toast.text2 = "Toast content";

// set tile notification properties for MPNS
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.tile = {};
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.tile.title = notificationText ;
notificationOptions.settings.mpns.tile.count = 1;

// set raw notification properties for WNS
notificationOptions.settings.wns = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.raw = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.raw.payload = {"custom":"data"};

// set toast notification properties for WNS
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast.launch = {"custom":"data"};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast.visual = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast.visual.binding = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast.visual.binding.template="ToastText04";
notificationOptions.settings.wns.toast.visual.binding.text=[{"content":"Text1"},{"content":"Text2"},{"content":"Text3"}];

// set tile notification properties for WNS
notificationOptions.settings.wns.tile = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.tile.visual = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.tile.visual.binding=[{"template":"TileSquareText04", "text": [{"content":"Text1"}]}, {"template":"TileWideText04","text": [{"content":"Text1"}]}];

// set badge notification properties for WNS
notificationOptions.settings.wns.badge = {};
notificationOptions.settings.wns.badge.value = 10;

return notificationOptions;
```

}

CLI Command:

```
E:\mfp projects\SampleMFP7\SampleMFP7P>mfp adapter call
? Which adapter do you want to use? httpAdapter
? Which endpoint do you want to use? httpAdapter/sendTagNotification
? Enter the comma-separated parameters:    "com_ibm_SampleMFP7","hello","tag1,tag2"
? How should the procedure be called? GET

 Calling GET '/SampleMFP7P/adapters/httpAdapter/sendTagNotification?params=["com_ibm_SampleMFP7","hello","tag1,tag2"]'

Response:

 {
  "result": "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): 'tag1,tag2'.",
  "isSuccessful": true
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132480/discussion-on-question-by-athista-lakshmi-selvaraj-push-notification-not-receive).

Comment: is the Device a real physical device or a emulator?

Comment: Its a physical device i.e tablet